# How can I download my whole site using FTP and still keep file permissions?

Tags: permissions, ftp, download, copy

I'm using Windows XP and have an FTP connection to my server. I would like to download the everything including file permissions as well. Filezila to my knowledge doesn't do that unless your on an Linux machine.

What should I do ?

Thank-you all
BigThings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ftp doesn't support transfer of file permission as it is platform independent - you can ftp to linux from windows, windows from linux ect... when you get the files to the local machine - you can do anything with them as your local folder permissions allows.